# Java forEach not working on flatMap using IntStream.range

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Starting with this trivial example from java2s:

```
 Stream.of("XML", "Java",  "CSS")
.flatMap(name ->  IntStream.range(0, name.length()).mapToObj(name::charAt))
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

the output is

```
X
M
L
J
a
v
a
C
S
S
```

I'm trying to understand what's going on inside the flatMap. I'd like to see the output of the IntStream.range, but I cannot get it to work. 
It seems you can whack a forEach(SOP) onto an IntStream.range(a,b) but when it's inside of the flatMap function, that can't be done (and I didn't at first notice that the whole of `name ->  IntStream.range(0, name.length()).mapToObj(name::charAt)` is the argument to the flatMap function.
How could I use the flatMap function with IntStream.range to convert the strings to a sequence of numbers corresponding to the lengths of the words?

I have tried this:

```
 Stream.of("XML", "Java",  "CSS")
        .flatMap(name ->  IntStream.range(0, name.length())) 
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

but it does not compile. I was expecting the line

```
.flatMap(name ->  IntStream.range(0, name.length()))
```

to take the strings and convert them to `0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2`. What am I misunderstanding? How can I get this sequence of numbers using the output of `name ->  IntStream.range(0, name.length())`?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your original code could be written as `Stream.of("XML", "Java",  "CSS")
.flatMapToInt(String::chars).forEach(c -> System.out.println((char)c));`, just saying…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler error is:

```
/MyClass.java:6: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
                .flatMap(name ->  IntStream.range(0, name.length())) 
                        ^
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
      IntStream cannot be converted to Stream<? extends R>)
  where R,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream
1 error
```

The important bit is:

> IntStream cannot be converted to Stream<? extends R>

An `IntStream` is a form of stream optimized for integers, but it's not directly compatible with `Stream<Integer>`.

You need to either call `boxed()` to convert it to a stream of objects:

```
Stream.of("XML", "Java",  "CSS")
        .flatMap(name ->  IntStream.range(0, name.length()).boxed()) 
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or call `flatMapToInt`:

```
Stream.of("XML", "Java",  "CSS")
        .flatMapToInt(name ->  IntStream.range(0, name.length())) 
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

You had the right idea, just needed a little tweaking to make Java understand you.